# Jupiter's moon Europa - is it possible to colonize Europa?

Tags: physics, moons, astronomy, solar-system, astrophysics

So basically, I have to write a thesis paper because I'm in the last year of high school. It is an independent research project and the culminating work of my studies in school, so it represents my ability to conduct research and write effectively.

The requirement is that the paper needs to be connected to one of my elective classes. I chose cosmology, so any topic related to cosmology or physics. I've done some research lately and what I would like to write about is Jupiter's moon Europa. More specifically, the question I would like to investigate is "Can humans live on Europa in the future?".

To answer this question, I am going to compare the environment on Europa with that of the Earth. If there are a lot of similiarites, then I will conclude that it is possible to settle on Europa. However, I am worried that it will be virtually impossible to compare the environments simply because there are too many factors to consider. For example, weather conditions, water availability, radiation, pressure, temperature and so on.

So I would like some advice. Firstly, which environmental factors should I include in my paper?

And secondly, if my question "Can humans live on Europa in the future?" is a bit too difficult to answer, then are there any other Europa-related questions that I could investigate instead?

Comment: Hello! This may be better suited to space exploration stack exchange. https://space.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: No SE community will do your homework for you.

Comment: I'm not looking for someone to do the paper for me. I'm just asking for Europa-related questions to examine for my project

Comment: *"I am going to compare the environment on Europa with that of the Earth. If there are a lot of similiarites, then I will conclude that it is possible to settle on Europa"* Oh dear, I get the impression you are considering the possibility of living mostly unprotected on the surface as we do on Earth, if that's so then you need to do some ***very*** basic research before going any further, like reading a book, or some Wikipedia articles.

Comment: Stephen H. Dole and Isaac Asimov, [*Planets for Man*](https://www.rand.org/pubs/commercial_books/CB183-1.html) (gentle, non-mathematical) and Stephen H. Dole, [*Habitable Planets for Man*](https://www.rand.org/pubs/commercial_books/CB179-1.html) (more technical), both published in 1964 by Blaisdell Publishing Company. Links go to freely available PDF scans at the RAND Corporation.

Comment: @AlexP I'm not sure books published in 1964 are the best option for him, we'd not even had our first fly-by back then and all we had was even more guesswork than we do now.

Comment: @Pelinore: It must be good to be able to form an opinion about a book without even bothering to look inside. For example, I don't know, the books might be about what conditions are needed, not about how to obtain them; like, how go about selecting a planet for people to live on, rather than how to go about making it suitable. Did I mention that the books were available free of charge?

Comment: @AlexP we had no close observations of it until 1979, knowing that is it really all that hard to conclude that something, and likely almost anything, published after that date would probably be a better option?

Comment: @Pelinore: We had no close observations of Earth before 1979? Those lazy scientists and geographers, what did we pay them for? Really, the books are **not** about any specific alien world. They are about, OK, assume that we can now travel around in the vicinity of the solar system, and we will probably find a lot of planets, how would one go about choosing one or another for colonization.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143069/discussion-between-pelinore-and-alexp).

Comment: " All these worlds are yours except Europa. " :-)